# Spring MVC Session check before every request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am developing a web app using spring boot and mvc. I have controllers and in every controller i have to check if session is exist. In example in getAll method i am checking if session is existing but i have to write this check code in every method , every controller. Is there any shortcut to do that?

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Sale")
public class SaleController
{
    @Autowired
    private SaleRepository saleRepository;
    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView getAll(@SessionAttribute(required=false) User user)
    {
        if(user==null)
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
        else
        {
            ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView("/view/sales.jsp");
            List<Sale> sales=saleRepository.findAll();
            modelAndView.addObject("sales",sales);
            return modelAndView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You *should* be using Spring Security, which performs this check for you for controllers that you say require a logged-in user. Furthermore, you're not checking if the *session* exists here; you're checking whether *a value inside the session* exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Filter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter) and apply it to all requests or only those matching a specific pattern.

To check for a session you would use [HttpServletRequest.getSession(false)](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession(boolean)) and check for null.